# Iterate over a list of objects on condition of a another array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of object below

the newlist is also dynamic and SelectID array is also dynamic

I am populating thorugh a function , now I have to iteratte and create the new list

```
  var newList = 
    [
    {  id : 1,name="tea",plant:"darjeeling"},
    {  id : 2,name="coffee",plant:"manipur"},
    {  id : 3,name="milk",plant:"nilgiri"},
    {  id : 4,name="tea",plant:"assam"}
    ]
```

anaother array which has ID in common

```
var selectedID = [2,3];
```

now I have to iterate over the list of objects and update the list of objects as
wherever the ID is 2 and 3  plant should be "munnar "

so how to create new list of objects "newlist"  like below

```
var newList = 
[
{  id : 1,name="tea",plant:"darjeeling"},
{  id : 2,name="coffee",plant:"munnar"},
{  id : 3,name="milk",plant:"munnar"},
{  id : 4,name="tea",plant:"assam"}
]
```

Comment: and where is your special problem?

Comment: op has not asked any question.

Comment: @Kinduser, rereaded, no question found o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are doing this in javascript, so first I want to point out you should have newList defined like this

```
 var newList = 
    [
    {  id : 1,name:"tea",plant:"darjeeling"},
    {  id : 2,name:"coffee",plant:"manipur"},
    {  id : 3,name:"milk",plant:"nilgiri"},
    {  id : 4,name:"tea",plant:"assam"}
    ]
```

name="tea" won't work.

But onto your problem, you'll want to use the selectedID array values to update your existing newList like so.

```
 var newList = 
    [
    {  id : 1,name:"tea",plant:"darjeeling"},
    {  id : 2,name:"coffee",plant:"manipur"},
    {  id : 3,name:"milk",plant:"nilgiri"},
    {  id : 4,name:"tea",plant:"assam"}
    ]

 var selectedID =[2,3]

for(i=0;i<newList.length;i++){
   for(j=0;j < selectedID.length;j++){
      if(newList[i].id==selectedID[j])
         newList[i].plant = "munnar";
   }
}

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: that would alter the `newList` based on index and not based on the `id` value.

Comment: cant alter the newlist , just have to change the values wherever its find the IDs

Comment: Here I fixed it... I can't stand that I did that wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the wanted id for changing, find the object and change the value.

Using:

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- and a default object `{}`, if no object is found.

```js
var newList = [{ id: 1, name: "tea", plant: "darjeeling" }, { id: 2, name: "coffee", plant: "manipur" }, { id: 3, name: "milk", plant: "nilgiri" }, { id: 4, name: "tea", plant: "assam" }],
    selectedID = [2, 3];

selectedID.forEach(id => (newList.find(a => a.id === id) || {}).plant = 'munnar');

console.log(newList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: dont know  why its not working in visual studio js file

Comment: @tripathy, it is ES6 style. but the better question is how many data do you have in `newList` and how many indices do you have in `selectedID`? how often does the content change? are the indices sorted?

Comment: indices wont be sorted they are just values coming from another function . SeletedID can containg many and also newlist can contain many object . but SelectedID will contain less or equal to the number of objects in list thats for sure

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you wish to manipulate the original array with different values based on an array of selected ids. If those selected ID's which could come from the UI match any of the ids in your array of plants then change the name to Munnar? If I have understood correctly then I believe the following should work for you

```
var newList = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "tea",
  plant: "darjeeling"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "coffee",
  plant: "manipur"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "milk",
  plant: "nilgiri"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "tea",
  plant: "assam"
}]

function munnar(selectedID) {
  newList.forEach( (item) => {
    selectedID.forEach( (id) => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        item.plant = 'Munnar'
      }
    })
  })
}

munnar([2, 3])
```

This returns

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "tea",
  plant: "darjeeling"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "coffee",
  plant: "Munnar"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "milk",
  plant: "Munnar"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "tea",
  plant: "assam"
}]
```